# How to compute the forward pass outputs for these weights and biases with python

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning

I am trying to do some dense neural network machine learning with python. I have a problem completing the code to compute the outputs from the weight and biases. When I apply operand `*` between the weight and the matrix element at a certain index I get the error that `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,784) (1000,784,1)`. Am I applying bad indexing to the loop or what am I doing wrong please help.

```
##initialize the training and test arrays
train=np.empty((1000,28,28),dtype='float64')
trainY=np.zeros((1000,10,1))
test=np.empty((10000,28,28), dtype='float64')
testY=np.zeros((10000,10,1))

##reading image data into the training array
#load the images
i=0
for filename in os.listdir('Data/Training1000/'):
    y=int(filename[0])
    trainY[i,y]=1.0
    train[i]=cv2.imread('Data/Training1000/{0}'.format(filename),0)/255.0
    i+=1

##reading image data into the testing array
i=0

for filename in os.listdir('Data/Test10000'):
    y = int(filename[0])
    testY[i,y] = 1.0
    test[i] = cv2.imread('Data/Test10000/{0}'.format(filename),0)/255.0 
    i=i+1

##reshape the training and testing arrays
trainX = train.reshape(train.shape[0],train.shape[1]*train.shape[2],1)
testX = test.reshape(test.shape[0],test.shape[1]*test.shape[2],1)
##section to declare the weights and the biases
w1 = np.random.uniform(low=-0.1,high=0.1,size=(numNeuronsLayer1,784))
b1 = np.random.uniform(low=-1,high=1,size=(numNeuronsLayer1,1))
w2 = np.random.uniform(low=-0.1,high=0.1,size=(numNeuronsLayer2,numNeuronsLayer1))
b2 = np.random.uniform(low=-0.1,high=0.1,size=(numNeuronsLayer2,1))

##declare the hidden layers
numNeuronsLayer1=100
numNeuronsLayer2=10
numEpochs=100

##declare a learning rate
learningRate = 0.1;

##do the forward pass on the weights and the biases
for n in range(0,numEpochs):
    loss=0
    trainX,trainY = shuffle(trainX, trainY)

    for i in range(trainX.shape[0]):
    ##this is where I have a problem, the line below throws the error described above
    ##my first pass is declared a2
    a2=w1*train[i]+w2*trainX[i]+b1
```

How do I correctly reference my training variables inside the loop above to  get rid of the broadcast error, Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close, but with a couple of problems. First, you need to be doing matrix multiplication. `*` will do element-wise multiplication (i.e., `np.array([1,2,3]) * np.array([2,3,4]) = np.array([2,6,12])`. To do matrix multiplication with `numpy` you can use the `@` operator (i.e., `matrix1 @ matrix2`) or use the `np.matmul` function.

You other problem is the shape of your inputs. I am not sure why you are adding a 3rd dimension (the `1` at the end of `train.reshape(train.shape[0],train.shape[1]*train.shape[2],1)`. You should be fine keeping it as a matrix (change it to `train.reshape(train.shape[0],train.shape[1]*train.shape[2])`, change the `test.reshape` accordingly.

finally, your inference line is a little off: `a2=w1*train[i]+w2*trainX[i]+b1`

You first must calculate `a1` before `a2`. An important part of matrix multiplication is that inner dimensions must agree (i.e., you cannot multiply matricies of shapes [100,50] and [100, 50] but you can multiply matricies of shapes [100,50] and [50, 60], the resulting shape of the matrix product is the outer indicies of each matrix, in this case [100,60]). As a result of matrix multiplication, you can also get rid of the for loop around training examples. All examples are calculated at the same time. So to calculate `a1`, we need to transpose our `w1` and have it as the right hand variable.

```
a1 = ( trainX @ w1.transpose() ) + b1.transpose()
```

then we can calcuate `a2` as a function of `a1`

```
a2 = ( a1 @ w2.transpose() ) + b2.transpose()
```

Comment: Am getting this error when I transpose  `matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 784 is different from 1)`

Comment: Which line should I edit?

Comment: You have to help man, please.

Comment: please paste the line thats erroring out, not just the message.

Comment: This is the line `a1 = ( trainX @ w1.transpose() ) + b1.transpose()`

Comment: did you change the `trainX.reshape` as I suggested before?

Comment: Yes you suggested changes but look at the original code and the target code I should change to they are the same.

Comment: I think we are misunderstanding each other. To confirm, you changed `trainX = train.reshape(train.shape[0],train.shape[1]*train.shape[2],1)` to `trainX = train.reshape(train.shape[0],train.shape[1]*train.shape[2])`

Comment: Ahh, I see, my mistake. See above comment.

Comment: Okay thanks implementing the changes, will let you know in a few.